# Facebook Graph API Nested request syntax to array

Tags: php, arrays, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to replicate Facebook's nested request syntax in PHP, converting the fields parameter into a multidimensional array.

```
/me?fields=name,updated_time,photos{name,source},likes{name,link},events.limit(4){name,start_time,end_time,photos}
```

Would result in something along the lines of...

```
Array
(
    [name]
    [updated_time]
    [photos] => Array
        (
            [name] 
            [source] 
        )
    [likes] => Array
        (
            [name] 
            [link] 
        )
)
```

Comment: And where are you stuck with doing this?

Comment: Preferably a for loop in PHP? Not sure what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to match the graph API Using a loop. Decided it would be best to keep the filter, and limit modifiers as part of the object in order to keep the array as clean as possible

```
     $a = $input;
     $output = array();
     $outputStacktrace = array(&$output);
     $depth = 0;
     $buffer = $key = '';
     $m = memory_get_usage();
     for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($a); $i++)
                 if ($a[$i] == ',') {
             if (strlen($buffer))
                            if($depth == 0){
                                if(is_array($outputStacktrace[0]) && empty($outputStacktrace[0])){
                                    $outputStacktrace[$depth][$buffer] = array();
                                }
                            } else {
                 $outputStacktrace[$depth][$key ? $key : count($outputStacktrace[$depth])] = $buffer;
                            }
                         $buffer = $key = '';
         } elseif ($a[$i] == '{') {
             $outputStacktrace[$depth][$buffer] = array();
             $outputStacktrace[$depth + 1] = &$outputStacktrace[$depth][$buffer];
             $depth++;
             $buffer = '';
         } elseif ($a[$i] == '}') {
             if (strlen($buffer))
                 $outputStacktrace[$depth][$key ? $key : count($outputStacktrace[$depth])] = $buffer;
             $buffer = $key = '';
             unset($outputStacktrace[$depth]);
             $depth--;
         } else {
             $buffer .= $a[$i];
                 }
                 if( $buffer!='' )
                $outputStacktrace[$depth][$key ? $key : count($outputStacktrace[$depth])] = $buffer;

                 return ($output);
```